# App not display in TestFlight

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I am facing an stupid issue.

While clicking on a link on email to download a beta test app in TestFlight, instead of showing the app in testflight its redirect me to app store to download TestFlight but my phone already have TestFlight. this is happening for all apps not for a specific.

any body have any idea why my iphone do that..

i am using IPhone 4S, IOS 8.1.2

This might be due to IOS 8.1.2.. do i need to change anything in my xcode project.

All apps are already running on many devices.. i have sent new request to some new devices.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There may be many reasons... So  I'll try to help you.

To who are you sending the email ? To a beta tester ? The email has to be the same then the App ID.

On the App Store, are you on the right store ? You should be on the store of your account and not on an other store.

I hope this helps,

Regards

Comment: I am doing what you have mentioned in your answer, but still user or even me, are unable to see app in testflight